# MySql RegexP in ShellSript is breaking

Tags: mysql, shell

I have a series of mysql scripts that run from a shell script. One of the queries includes

```
Select * from Table where FieldX Regex 'XYZ$'
```

in other words 'ends with XYZ'.  However this is breaking the script.  If I remove the `$` or make it literal `\$` it works but neither serves my purpose. Is there an altnerative character I can use that Regexp will understand as 'end of line' and Shell Script won't object to?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using single quotes to delimit the shell string, you need to use double quotes to delimit MySQL strings inside it.

```
'and FieldX Regex "XYZ$"
```

Comment: @Baymar In my case the entire mysql string is inside quotes so "Select * from TableX where FieldX Regex 'XYZ'".

Comment: Then you need to escape the double quotes inside. Please update the question with a [mcve].

Comment: If you put the entire string in single quotes, you can use double quotes around the regexp.

Comment: It's not any clearer. You say this is in a shell script, so show the code.

Comment: If it's in a double quoted string, you need to escape the `$` since that's used for variables.